# Can't execute Query in db2 using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am trying to execute a query in db2. While the statement "SELECT PacientID FROM Spital.Pacient" works without a problem in the CLP, it doesn't work in the java program I wrote.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        Connection myConn = DB2Conn1.openConnection("admin", "admin", "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/MYDB");

        if(!myConn.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Connectat!");
        }
        String nume;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        stmt = myConn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PacientID FROM Spital.Pacient");

        while(rs.next()) {
            nume = rs.getString(1);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        DB2Conn1.closeConnection(myConn);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Console Output:

```
  Connectat!
 com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204,      SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SPITAL.PACIENT, DRIVER=3.69.49
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.c(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.d(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.h(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.ib(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at mydbprog.tester.main(tester.java:19)
```

Comment: Does `"SELECT PacientID FROM Spital.\"Pacient\""` change anything ?

Comment: 204 is usually a spelling error.

Comment: @Berger: thank you for your input! that did it!